# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[Models.MailListViewModel]'

Tags: linq-to-sql, model-view-controller

I am getting an error saying:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[WebUI.Models.MailListViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebUI.Models.MailListViewModel'.

This is in my controller:

```
public ViewResult List()
    { var mailToShow = from m in mailRepository.Mail
                         join p in profilesRepository.Profiles on m.SenderId equals p.ProfileId 
                         select new MailListViewModel
                                    {
                                        SenderId = m.SenderId,
                                        ProfileId = p.ProfileId,
                                        UserName = p.UserName,
                                        Subject = m.Subject
                                    }; 
       return View(mailToShow);
    }
```

This is in my MailListViewModel:

```
public class MailListViewModel
{        
    public int SenderId;
    public int ProfileId;
    public string UserName;
    public string Subject;
}
```

This is in my view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<WebUI.Models.MailListViewModel>" %>

<% foreach (var m in (IEnumerable)Model)
       { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>TODO image</td>   
        <td>
        <%: Model.SenderId %></td>

        <td><%: Model.Subject%></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
```

The error message seems to be conflicting, saying that I am using the correct model.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is returning an `IQueryable<MailListViewModel>`, essentially one `MailListViewModel` for every result in the query. Your view is expecting only a single `MailListViewModel`.

You should update your view to expect `IEnumerable<MailListViewModel>`, like so:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WebUI.Models.MailListViewModel>>" %>
```

Also, once you've done that you shouldn't cast the `Model` to `IEnumerable` as that will result in each item in the enumeration being treated as type `object` so it will appear as though none of your properties exist.

Comment: Great, almost working now!

After I updated the view, I got the message:
CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Subject' and no extension method 'Subject' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It was highlighting:
<%: m.Subject %>

Intellisense said:
Cannot resolve symbol 'Subject'

What should I try next?

Comment: If you're still casting your model to IEnumerable it's probably that. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Closer :) Now I'm getting an error saying:
"The query contains references to items defined on a different data context."
and it is referring to the line:"<% foreach (var m in Model)"

Comment: You can't join across two data contexts. You have to either just use one or convert to a (filtered) list (.ToList()) and then join the lists as that will use LinqToObjects.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try two different queries for now and see if that works, but if not, I'll try the List solution.

Comment: I ended up combining the two data contexts into one and now it's working.